# Skinless Sausages why they disintegrate?

Tags: sausages

A lot of sausages these days appear to be made skinless.  Ok, this is not a problem, but they do tend to disintegrate in the pan.  First off, why, and secondly, how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Are you asking about bulk sausage (basically, ground meat), or something actually sausage-shaped without a casing, or something else? Can you give us an example photo or link, or if not, a bit more detail?

Comment: @Jefromi the latter certainly exists. [This is a common brand](http://m.tesco.com/h5/groceries/r/www.tesco.com/groceries/product/details/?id=257447210).

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want skinless sausages, and are similar regular sausages available? And which kind, traditional sausage or hot dog type (finely ground)? For traditional sausage, I just remove the casing after cooking them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They disintegrate simply because the skin of normal sausages is what holds them together, and that's not there. Cooking them in the oven using [non-stick sheet](http://www.lakeland.co.uk/5570/Magic-Reusable-Non-Stick-Baking-Tray-Liner-Sheet-25cm-x-50cm) (this is one brand but there are others) is probably the best way to keep them intact, but possibly not what you want to do. They also stay together under the grill (broiler) but watch for them leaving bits behind on the bars of the grill pan. If you really want to fry them, be gentle, and tilt the pan to turn them at least until the outside is browned and a bit stronger.

Comment: If the outside is browned a bit, then surely the sausage will still disintegrate, I will try this however, thanks.

Comment: @dougal you'd still have to be gentle but the cooked outer layer should hold it together rather like cooking a burger